# Fastapi: Memory leak in Google Cloud

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi, pydantic, uvicorn

i'm running a fastapi in google cloud and it seems like i have a memory leak,

[picture of memory leak in google cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTmth.png)

```
fastapi==0.95.1
pydantic==1.10.7
uvicorn==0.22.0
python-dotenv==0.15.0
fastapi_oidc==0.0.9
sqlalchemy==2.0.13
psycopg2==2.9.6
pg8000==1.29.5
slowapi>=0.1.8
fastapi-cache2[redis]==0.2.1
alembic>=1.7.5
aioredis==2.0.1
asyncpg==0.27.0
```

i'm using python:3.10

the cmd to run the server is the following:

```
alembic upgrade head && uvicorn app.main:app --proxy-headers --host 0.0.0.0 --port $API_PORT --workers $WORKERS
```

have anyone seen anything similar to this and what did you do to fix it?

if you need anything else from me let me know

i tried updating the python version on the container
i tried updating all the libraries to new versions
i tried fixing all the code bugs resulting in errors

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then use the _Edit_ function to modify your question accordingly.

The practice of boiling the code down to the bare minimum needed to capture the essence of the problem not only motivates others to actually try and help you but more often than not gives you a deeper understanding to solve the problem yourself.